# Terminal command / Script to show files by their type and size

Tags: linux, bash, file, sorting, size

I have to constantly handle a huge number of files that need sorting - by their size and their file type. Please share any suggestions you have for a bash script or a terminal command (with the right parameters) that would sort files by the above-mentioned criteria. A big plus would be for the script to also show the actual number of files by file-type, as so:

- 831 JPEG Files / 566MB
- 122 MP4 Files / 4000MB
- 98 ZIP Files / 50MB

I'm rather new at Linux, so any feedback on what the different parts of this script/command do will be awesome, as I'd like to understand how it actually works.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: The solutions above are not valid, as they're not doing what I've outlined is needed in my original post.

Lets say I have a directory called boo/

I want something which will provide a result as the one in my original query - not list all the files and have their individual size next to them. 

Something like this: 

1GB - JPEGS in boo/
2GB - MP4s in boo/
3GB - MP3s in boo/

I'm finding it hard to explain this any simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
ls -lshR
```

using switch `-h` you can read easily dimension (human readable), with switch `-R` you can go inside a folder recursively.

eventually you can save the input and find file type using `grep` command:

```
$ ls /your_dir -lshR > your_file
```

now you can search the files

```
$ grep -e .mp4 your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

List by size:

```
ls -lS
```

Only list files containing ".txt":

```
ls | grep .txt
```

Count files containing ".txt":

```
ls | grep .txt | wc -l
```

Comment: Now I have to figure out how to stick these in a script. 

Thanks! If anyone has more suggestions, they're welcome to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

Are you assuming that the file name extension determines the type of file?  This is not necessarily the case in Linux, where we tend to test the actual file contents.  To do this you can use the `file` command:

```
file Kalimba.mp3
```

returns

```
Kalimba.mp3:    MPEG-1 Layer 3 with ID3v2
```

Comment: No, he's assuming that files with the same extension will be counted together.